# How do you count documents in a firestore collection using the admin SDK?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I tried `CollectionReference`.`count` as in the documentation [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html#count) (`admin.firestore().collection("users").count()`)
but it says

> TypeError: collectionReference.count is not a function

I also tried: (`admin.firestore().collection("users").countDocuments()`)

And still:

> TypeError: collectionReference.countDocuments is not a function

Comment: Should I post a new issue on Github for this?

Comment: No need to post a new issue on Github. Give me a moment let me write out the answer.

Comment: Awesome! take your time

Answer (score 2):

To get the size of a collection, do this:

According to the Count [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#use_the_count_aggregation): The server calculates the count, and transmits only the result, a single integer, back to your app, saving on both billed document reads and bytes transferred, compared to executing the full query.

```js
// Below is in preview 
const collectionRef = admin.firestore().collection('users');
const snapshot = await collectionRef.count().get();
console.log(snapshot.data().count);

// below will fetch all the data and count it. It is more expensive.
const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection("users").get();
// your function should be async
console.log('collection size is: ', snapshot.size);

// or
console.log('collection size is: ', snapshot.docs.length);
```

You must fetch the collection before getting the length.

Comment: This seems to work even though I can't find documentation for this API. Plus, doesn't this work by reading all documents first? I was hoping for an approach that gets the count directly without having to read all documents

Comment: No, for flutter, you can't count the documents without reading it. The docs for firestore api (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) although `size` property was not mentioned.

Comment: But in that case, the documentation is also misleading because as in the link I included, it mentioned a count function that doesn't read all documents

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought we were using flutter. for Javascript, the count function should work (but note, it is in preview) and the way you wrote yours won't work. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Please checkout the updated answer.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried ( the code under ```// Below is in preview```) but it showed the error that count is not a function

Comment: maybe it is only available on the preview version. Are you using the latest preview sdk?